# DateField format in DjangoTemplate

Tags: django, django-templates

I am using paginator to divide reviews on pages, my model has DateField

```
 created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I am using ajax to do it without refreshing page.
When i put it in my template like this

```
{{review.created}}
```

It displays in format like 06 June 2021
But with ajax, where i pass

```
'date':obj.created
```

It displays in format 2021-06-06
How can i made it to display similiar in one of these formats?
I prefer first format, but second will be acceptable too

Comment: Just use this:

`{{review.created |date:'Y-m-d'}}` . You can find template tags filters on django docs

Comment: @Mirza715 Thank you, it helped, i tried it but in different order, and it's displayed as name of month still, so i suggested that its doesn't work for me